# Adding a directory of files to PATH

Tags: bash, path

I'm trying to add a set of subdirectory's to my PATH in as simple a way as possible.

Currently the structure is:

```
main_project/
   subproject/bin/
   subproject2/bin/
   subproject with spaces/bin/
```

I'm currently using the simple bash-fu in my .bash_profile:

`PATH="$PATH:$(echo /projects/main_project/*/bin | tr ' ' ':')"`

The problem is the path with spaces comes out as:

`subproject:with:spaces/bin/` in my $PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `printf` instead:

```
PATH="$PATH$(printf ":%s" /projects/main_project/*/bin)"
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop would be clearer:

```
for subproj in /projects/main_project/*/bin; do
    PATH+=":$subproj"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (abusing `IFS`—but it's here for this kind of purposes too!):

```
scratch=( /projects/main_project/*/bin )
IFS=: read -r PATH <<< "$PATH:${scratch[*]}"
```

---

The stuff below is probably overkill and useless for your purpose!

If you want something more robust, that works as expected even if `PATH` is unset or null:

```
scratch=( /projects/main_project/*/bin )
IFS=: read -r PATH <<< "${PATH:+$PATH:}${scratch[*]}"
```

Finally you might (rightly!) think that it's not safe to use globs without any safety (i.e., without the shell option `nullglob` or `failglob`) set:

```
old_nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)
shopt -s nullglob
scratch=( /projects/main_project/*/bin )
((${#scratch})) && IFS=: read -r PATH <<< "${PATH:+$PATH:}${scratch[*]}"
$old_nullglob
```

Another thought, what if these are already in your `PATH`? I'll leave it as homework!